# Regex find URL with the first extension

Tags: python, regex

I have string like below

```
string = 'https://somewebsite.com/itesr0824/products/YYA-002/fdrop-tQ?position=6'
```

How can I find

```
'https://somewebsite.com/itesr0824'
```

with regex?

I've tried

```
re.sub('[^https://somewebsite.com/[a-zA-Z0-9].+$','',string)
```

but it only finds

```
'https://somewebsite.com/itesr0824/products/YYA'
```

Comment: try this `re.sub('https://somewebsite.com/[a-zA-Z0-9]+','', string)`

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: Try a positive look ahead: `"https://somewebsite\.com/[^/]+(?=/products)"`. Which means: find the strings consisting of `https://somewebsite.com/` + `any non-slash string longer than 1` that has `/products` after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

string = 'https://somewebsite.com/itesr0824/products/YYA-002/fdrop-tQ?position=6'

x = re.sub('https://somewebsite\.com/\w+','',string)

# where: 
# \w - matches any letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]
# + - one or more

print(x)
```

Prints

```
/products/YYA-002/fdrop-tQ?position=6
```

Comment: Just a small comment: The '.' (dot) character matches any character. If you only want to match 'somewebsite.com' you should use an escape to match the dot.

Comment: This implements quite literally the *exact* opposite of the OP's requirement: "*How can I find `https://somewebsite.com/itesr0824` with regex?*"

Comment: Looks like OP tries to `find` something in order to `replace` it.

Comment: Please never use `[\w\d]`. `\w` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why on Earth would you use regular expressions for this when Python has a built-in URL parser? Don't re-invent the wheel and needlessly require accounting for all the weird edge cases URLs might present for you and instead use `urllib.parse.urlparse()` and `urllib.parse.urljoin`:

```
import urllib.parse
string = "https://somewebsite.com/itesr0824/products/YYA-002/fdrop-tQ?position=6"
parsedURL = urllib.parse.urlparse(string)
trimmedURL = urllib.parse.urljoin(parsedURL.scheme + "://" + parsedURL.netloc, parsedURL.path.split("/")[1]) # 'https://somewebsite.com/itesr0824'
```